# During Heroku Post Build, Cannot find file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

This is a react application, with styled components, with a Node backend being deployed to Heroku via `git push heroku master`

I import the style for each component from a separate file  with `import {...} from './style'`.

Where the file structure is:

`OptionsCarousel
    |index.js
    |style.js`

This makes perfect sense to me, and works locally both via `npm start` and `npm run build -> serve -s build`. With no issues. But when deploying to Heroku, during the optimization build stage, it fails with the error:

`remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:
remote:        ./src/OptionsCarousel/index.js
remote:        Cannot find file './style' in './src/OptionsCarousel'.`

Any advice on a better way to structure this, and what is causing the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Heroku builds from `master` as a default (you can deploy from another branch tho). Are you sure that you've added/committed all your files to master and then done `git push heroku master` or however you're deploying your code. FWIW I use the same component structure (CSS modules rather than CSS in JS) and had no issues with pushing to heroku.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, good to hear that I haven't lost my marbles. I am committing to master and using `git push heroku master`, I may investigate how heroku caches files, as the entire structure has been changed to accommodate styled-components. So, it may be associated with that.

Comment: Yeah. You can clear the build cache with [these instructions](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache). Hope you fix it ok.

Comment: Cheers @Andy, clearing the cache resolved the issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per @Andy's comment, I needed to clear the cache as I had made significant changes to the file structure in the repository. I followed these [instructions](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache) to do that.