# Cannot deploy to heroku because cannot find file

Tags: git, github, heroku, deployment

I use heroku to deploy my react app. It used to work fine but now when I run the command

> git push heroku master

I see the following error:

```
remote: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:
remote:        ./src/service/TodoService.js
remote:        Cannot find file './constants' in './src/service'.
```

I spent more than an hour trying to figure out the cause. Tried answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54086013/cannot-find-file-on-trying-to-deploy-to-heroku-works-locally) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960033/during-heroku-post-build-cannot-find-file). They did not help me.
I decided to check the file that caused the build fail in my github repository and I found that its name was different from the name on my computer.

Here is the github:

[image]

And this is the file on my computer:

[image]

Seems like Github did not notice that I renamed this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I used the answer from [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/server-unable-to-see-files-inside-of-imports-folder-on-heroku/37824/4).
Basically you need to rename the file that causes build failure so git can track it.

> git mv Constants.js constants.js

Then commit, push and make sure that the name on github is corrent. After that you should be able to successfully deploy to heroku

Answer (score 2):

It's case sensitive. Make sure to keep your naming consistent.